# Alterar valor vindo do back para o front end (na service)

Tags: angular, typescript, services

Estou recebendo um objeto de back distinto (normalmente tenho um back padrao) por conta disso os valores dos id vieram divergentes do que preciso, gostaria de altera-los na service para que se encaixe no meu front porem não sei como fazer isso.

por exemplo
**Eu espero** um objeto com id e value
**o back esta** me retornando codigo e valor

segue o que tentei fazer

```
Ajuste(model: any): PessoaFisica {
  if (!model) {
    return model;
  }

  return {
    ...model,
idade && idade.codigo{idade.id}
```

}

mas não funcionou

espero que dê pra entende

Comment: Na verdade não deu pra entender não, como assim **"Estou recebendo um objeto de back distinto"**?

Comment: eu geralmente consulto um back e vem tudo bonitinho, mas esse dados em particular então vindk de outro sistema, não posso alterar back, pelo fato de ja estar sendo utilizado

Comment: Bom se entendi basta no seu model (creio que haja um) no Angular, adicionar as propriedades que estão faltando e utilizá-las.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está utilizando o `HttpClient`? Se sim, você pode usar o operator `map` do RxJs para mudar o tipo, assim:

```
this.objetoConvertido = this.httpClient.get<ObjetoIdValue>('suapibackend').pipe(map(resposta =>{
  const conversion = {id: resposta.codigo, value: resposta.valor}
  return conversion;
}));
```